# Can I restrict viewport render to inside the camera

Tags: rendering, interface, 3d-view

Is it possible to enable viewport rendering, but when in camera mode, restrict it to only inside the camera?

My current workaround is to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> for render boarders, and select as much of my camera as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, albeit through a rather cumbersome process.

1. Select a border larger than the camera (this will set the border how you want, but then disable it)
2. Re-enable render border

[image]

I actually [wrote a patch](https://developer.blender.org/D712) to expedite this process by removing the "auto disable" behavior. However opinion was divided on weather or not removing the auto disabling was an improvement (IMO it is), so the patch was not accepted (yet!)..

If you have any feedback or ideas how to implement a faster, more convenient workflow, by all means leave a comment on the [revision page](https://developer.blender.org/D712) :)

Comment: I agree that your patch would have been the right way to go!

Comment: It seems that things working now. I guess the issue has been fixed (at least in the current v2.78).

Answer (score 5):

Pablo Vazquez has created an addon called the [Amaranth Toolset](http://pablovazquez.org/amaranth/) which (among a ton of other useful features) adds a way to do exactly what you are looking for.

Once the addon is installed just go into camera view and hit <kbd>W</kbd> > *camera as render border*.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I know I came a bit late to this question but in newer versions of Blender, I'm currently on 2.78c, there is a check box under the dimensions tab that allows you to do this. The checkbox is labelled `Border`

[image]

Comment: @cegaton Whoops my bad. I will fix the image when I next switch computer on. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a different way to do it or they changed it in Blender 3 but I achieved this by toggling "Render Region" on:

[image]